# Subscribe to ActionsSubject on father component is not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, subscribe, ngrx-effects

I'm having a problem with a subscribe that it seems to not be working since it is shadowed by it's children.

The architecture is pretty much like this: I have a form that display a list of users. This form contains a hidden component (`UpdateUserComponent`) like this

```
  <app-update-user (navigation)="navigate($event)" [user]="user" *ngIf="feature === 'update'"></app-update-user>
```

that will be displayed based on a user action. 
The `UpdateUserComponent` contains only the logic to dispatch the `UpdateUser` action and is like this:

```
<app-form-user [user]="user" [roles]="roles" [canHandleRoles]="canHandleRoles" (fromForm)="fromForm($event)"></app-form-user>
```

So it will display the `FormUserComponent` which is the form to update the user.

I wanted to subscribe to the `NGRX-Action` that is dispatched from the Effects after the user has been successfully updated, and I put this code:

```
constructor(
  private actions: ActionsSubject) {
}
this.subscription.add(this.actions.pipe(
  filter((action: Action) => action.type === UsersActionTypes.UserUpdated)
).subscribe(action => {
  //here do stuff needed when the user has been successfully updated
}));
```

Inside the `UpdateUserComponent`, the father of `FormUserComponent`, but it is not able to catch any action, meanwhile the same code inside the `FormUserComponent` is able to successfully catch the action.
It seems like the fact that `UpdateUserComponent` is being shadowed because it is the father of `FormUserComponent`

Comment: `<app-update-user (navigation)="navigate($event)" [user]="user" *ngIf="feature === 'update'"></app-update-user>`. Can you please remove this `*ngIf` condition and verify the same code. Because I'm doubtful that your updateUserComponent is getting destroyed while it's working fine in formusercomponent because subscription is alive in that. Please verify this.

Comment: what is this.subscription ?

Comment: @MsuArven is the object that I'm using to store the subscriptions and then I will unsubsribe on the onDestroy

Comment: The onDestroy is not being called at all

Comment: @DavideQuaglio- if onDestroy of updateUserComponent is not called then subscription should work in that component too. Still please verify once by removing that condition.

Comment: @walter I removed the OnDestroy method and with bot subscribe active, in both components only the `FormUserComponent` is being able to catch the action, the other `UpdateUserComponent` is not able to catch any action at all

Comment: remove this condition  `*ngIf="feature === 'update'"` from <app-update-user></<app-update-user> then check

Comment: @walter nothing, it doesn't change much, except some stuff not working correctly